# Retrieve Mdex.com exchange rates for token pair [Huobi Eco Chain]

Tags: exchange-api, decentralized-exchange

After long Telegram conversations I have found out that [MdexSwap](https://ht.mdex.com/#/swap) uses a secret formula to calculate their token exchange rates on their swap platform. Unlike [Uniswap](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/protocol-overview/how-uniswap-works/) they also don't really have an API, SDK or any other documentation for developers at least what I have found out after intense researching for more than a week. I have found [their](https://github.com/mdexSwap) Github and some kind of [API](https://api.mdex.com/) but that's it and as said before it doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned it seems they have a particular way of doing things, and I am not too familiar with Mdex, but I have worked with Uniswap's sub-graph implementation. This isn't necessarily a solution to your question but may help you get there.

After looking into https://info.mdex.com I spotted that they use a similar approach to Uniswap's sub-graph. They implement the GraphQL approach that come from TheGraph (https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2).

I came across this GraphiQL playground they have set-up (https://graph.mdex.com/subgraphs/name/mdex/swap/graphql). On the right hand-side you can explore the available queries they provide (Docs) and hopefully you can figure out what you are trying to accomplish here.

Here's a quick example of what you can achieve (GraphQL) Just paste it into the left on that GraphiQL, this gets you some pairs data with their available reserves.

```
query pairsData {
  pairs(first: 10) {
    id
    reserve0
    reserve1
    token0 {
      name
      symbol
    }
    token1 {
      name
      symbol
    }
  }
}
```